Email not populating properly if there is & in the body in outlook
$"/c ipm.note /m \"?subject={subject}  &body={body}\"";

the command used to populate subject and body. If there is & symbol in the body, its breaking at the symbol.
Tried Uri.EscapeDataString but showing encoded symbols in the mail body.

What's the context here? Where are you running this /c ipm.note command?

If the body is HTML E-mail, then you need to escape the ampersand to &amp;, so ?subject=foo&amp;body=123

@Dai I am sending text from c# application to outllook and have to separate text for subject and body. "&subject=somerandomtext&body=somerandomtext&content " this is the example and should come like some random text in mail subject and some randomtext&content in mail body. But in outlook its breaking at some random text because of '&' symbol
